# How would I skip a specific event using boolean flag?

Tags: javascript, events, boolean, flags, touchstart

I'm making a function that combined 2 events in single `on` method for controlling, editing more better and easily like this:

```js
class EventManager {
  constructor($el) {
    this.$el = $el;
    this.mainSwitch = false;
    this.subSwitch = false;
    this.condition = (!this.mainSwitch && !this.subSwitch); // false false then
    this.condition2 = (!this.mainSwitch && this.subSwitch); // false true then
  }
  start(e) {
    if (this.condition) {
      console.log(e.type);
      this.mainSwitch = true;
      return false; // return keyword for end the function
    } else if (this.condition2) {
      this.mainSwitch = false;
      this.subSwitch = false; // Go back to the default statement.
      return false;
    }
    return false;
  }
  move(e) {
    if (this.mainSwitch == true && this.subSwitch == false) {
      console.log(e.type);
    }
  }
  end(e) {
    if (this.mainSwitch == true && this.subSwitch == false) {
      console.log(e.type);
      this.mainSwitch = false;
      this.subSwitch = true;
    }
  }
  apply() {
    this.$el.on('touchstart mousedown', (e) => {
      this.start(e);
    })
    $('html').on({
      ['touchmove mousemove']: (e) => this.move(e),
      ['touchend mouseup']: (e) => this.end(e)
    })
  }
}
var thatEvent = new EventManager($('#link'));
thatEvent.apply();
```

```css
      a {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: brown;
        font-family: Helvetica;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
      }
```

```html
    <a id="link" target="_blank" href="https://google.co.uk" draggable="false">
      Click/Touch and Drag/Swipe
    </a>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I've added boolean flags for skipping a specific `events group` which is `mouseevents` because this code runs twice when I `touch` the element.

The issue is, boolean flags doesn't skip the `mousedown` event as I expected. After `this.condition2` managed, it rolls back for comparing `this.condition`. And then fires `console.log(e.type)`.

At first, I thought boolean flags could skip the `event`. Because I added `return` keyword every `if` sections for cutting off the function after the comparing had done.

This issue causes that `mousedown` event is going to disable permanently. For using the `mousedown` event, both flags, `this.mainSwitch` and `this.subSwitch` should be set as `falses` but after I managed the `touchstart`, the boolean values set as `false` and `true` so the `mousedown` event can't use anymore.

Are there any ways to actual skip the event using boolean flags in javascript?

Comment: value of `this.condition` also `this.condition2` is not being change in your events .. you only change the `mainswitch` and `subswitch` variable. 
it doesnt mean that you change those two will aso change the `this.condition` variable. because value of this is being set from initialization/contructor only

Comment: better change your `this.condition` object into a function to make it more dynamic. so it will always rely on your mainswitch and subswitch

Comment: @JohnChristianDeChavez :o I thought the values of `constructor` would change it when i used it inside of the function. It works as I wanted after your advice. Thank you so much

Comment: No, constructor run only once you initialised the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

value of `this.condition` also `this.condition2` is not being change in your events.

you only change the `mainswitch` and `subswitch` variable. it doesnt mean that you change those two will aso change the `this.condition` variable. because value of this is being set from `initialization/contructor` only

better change your `this.condition` object into a function to make it more dynamic. so it will always rely on your mainswitch and subswitch